# AS3: Boolean variables changing by themselves?

Tags: actionscript-3, boolean

Yes, you've read the title correctly. It appears that somehow Boolean variables switch to true by themselves. This is the only way I can explain this. Is this somehow possible? I have a Boolean that is set to false and can only be changed under strict conditions, but somehow it gets changed anyway, along with all the other Boolean variables. Any logical explanation for this?

Comment: explain more detailed... What IDE are you using? are you coding on the timeline? Is not posible for an variable to togle just like that...must be some event... Show as some code dude... I think you are coding on the timeline and the frames are tricking you.

Comment: No, it's not changing by itself. :) If you use a getter/setter you could put a break-point in the setter function and see when it's getting set.

Comment: I'm using FlashDevelop along with Flash CC. I didn't attach any code because, well, I really doubt that'll help. basically it goes like this: if(objectsAddedToScreen == objectsRemovedFromScreen && bossWave && bossDeath && bossSoulsSpawned && endWaveControl == false && uselessVariable == false), the variables are toggling back right after these conditions are met. It's a pretty huge chunk of code to post, but I will if it's needed. As about the getter/setter, thanks for the tip, I was trying to figure out how to trace what exactly toggles the variable.

Comment: it might be a long shot but a rookie mistake is doing something like `if (myBool = true)` (instead of `==`) with the info you provided this is my best guess (and no, booleans don't change "by themselves", things would fall apart pretty quickly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you provide no code, I'll answer giving you ability to find out what is changing your variable.

Since you mention you are using FlashDevelop, I'll give you a FlashDevelop specific answer.

1. As noted by comments, using a getter/setter method will allow you to put a break point in your code.  So instead of something like `private var myBool:Boolean;` do this:

   ```
   private var myBool_:Boolean = false; //the actual var
   public function get myBool():Boolean { return myBool; }
   public function set myBool(val:Boolean):void { 
       myBool_ = val;
   }
   ```
2. Now in flash develop, set a break point on this line:  `myBool_ = val;`.  To set a break point, click just to the left of the line in the gutter (see where the red dot is in the screenshot)
3. Run your code, look over to the **Stack** panel, and double click the the second line.  That will show you what is setting your variable.

[image]

[Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rRye.jpg)

Comment: So as far as I understood, the problem lied within a listener function which wasn't removed. Thanks a lot for this method, but for some reason my application froze right after the output. I'll try using this way of tracing variables in the future anyway, thanks for a valuable advice.